# Formatting an individual column in Access "Table/Query" listbox

Tags: oracle, ms-access, vba

I have listbox with 1 columns populated with an Oracle based ADODB Recordset using

```
strsql = "SELECT '£' || expected_cost as ""Cost"""
lstComm.RowSourceType = "Table/Query"
Set lstComm.
Recordset = rs
```

The query returns £1.58, but the listbox displays #1.58.

If I use

```
strsql = "trim(TO_CHAR(round(expected_cost,2), 'L9999999999999.99')) as ""Cost"""
```

The query returns £1.58, but the listbox displays $1.58.

Is there a way to populate the column as UK currency, whilst keeping the RowSourceType as "Table/Query"?

Comment: This is strange: it looks like your `TO_CHAR` does not return a string but a currency. Eventually try to concatenate an empty string BEFORE the number ? Something like `'£'+TO_CHAR(round(expected_cost,2), 'L9999999999999.99')` ( I am no expert in Oracle idiom - not sure if it's `+` or `&`....

Comment: @PatrickHonorez I tried select '£'||TO_CHAR(round(expected_cost,2), 'L9999999999999.99') and this brought back #$1.58

Comment: Can you replace the expression by a stupid constant, like 'hello' to make sure you're modifying the right source ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: Yes.

The easiest (and best) way to accomplish this is to use a `Currency` format type. From there you just change the `Format` field from `Currency` to `£#,##0.00;(£#,##0.00)`

Comment: The SQL query is for Oracle, so I cannot use Currency